# Convert Curl POST API request to Subprocess call in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, curl, flask, subprocess

I have a curl request that works properly in command line in python3. The API is written in flask rest framework.

```
curl -d '{"text":"Some text here.", "category":"some text here"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://xx.xx.x.xx/endpoint
```

I converted this request into a subprocess request

```
txt = 'Some text here'
tmp_dict = {"text":txt, "category":"text"}
proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-d", str(tmp_dict), '-H', "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/endpoint"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
out = eval(out.decode("utf-8"))
```

Error (I return a response `status_code` 400 when no text is passed in the request, which is obviously not the case here)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/joel/.virtualenvs/p3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-35-324f7c5741fc>", line 6, in <module>
    out = eval(out.decode("utf-8"))

  File "<string>", line 1
    NO TEXT INPUT
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I send the request with text, it works properly but that is not what I intend to do.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-d", '{"text":"Some text here.", "title":"some text here"}', '-H', "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/endpoint"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: What's the point of calling curl from a Python program? Python can do HTTP requests, you don't have to call an external process for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a valid json body in your curl request. Right now you are sending a string in json body which is not valid.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-d", str(tmp_dict), '-H', "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/endpoint"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

So instead of using **`str(tmp_dict)`** (it wraps your dict in single quotes which is not a valid JSON), you should use **`json.dumps(tmp_dict)`** (which produces a string which is according to JSON format). So change the above line to:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-d", json.dumps(tmp_dict), '-H', "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/endpoint"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```